# {Stipulativism vs. ostensivism} vs. {Formalism/if-then-ism vs. ante rem realism}

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics, definitions

The [SEP article on definitions](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/definitions/) includes the following two passages:

> See Frege 1914 for a defense of the austere view that, in mathematics at least, only stipulative definitions should be countenanced.

And:

> The capacity of ostensive definitions to introduce essentially new vocabulary has led some thinkers to view them as the source of all primitive concepts. Thus, Russell maintains in Human Knowledge that
>
> > all nominal definitions, if pushed back far enough, must lead ultimately to terms having only ostensive definitions, and in the case of an empirical science the empirical terms must depend upon terms of which the ostensive definition is given in perception. (p. 242)

Now depending on how hard and fast one holds to distinctions between schematic propositions, axioms, axiom schemes, etc. as far as things like truth-aptitude go, one might or might not be tempted to hold that some definition sentences are axioms. That is, if a thoroughly schematic sentence is not truth-apt, and if a mathematical definition is hardly anything more than a thoroughly schematic sentence of some sort, then it is hard to see how truth-apt a mathematical definition could be. At "best," a stipulative definition is true because it has been somehow defined as true.<sup>♃</sup>

Allowing for the time being that some schematic sentences, even if thoroughly schematic, are for some other "reason" still truth-apt in a substantive way (perhaps there is an erotetic "way out" in terms of schematic questions having correct or incorrect schematic answers?), or waiving the issue of schematics altogether, let's just say that if a definition sentence can be true and if it is not inferred (here probably conjunctively, as by a conjunction of other definition sentences), then it is an axiom; this is our stipulative definition of *axiom* for the purposes of the argument, no less. So stipulative definitions might be axiomatic in flavor.

However, it seems like ostensive definitions would be, too. But whereas a stipulative axiom seems like a piece of formalist or perhaps even logicist machinery, an ostensive axiom seems like it would be meant to refer "by name" (but indexically, otherwise) to something. (Paradoxically, the overlap between the notions of an indexical, a variable, and a scheme lends itself to characterizing ostensive definition sentences as too schematic to be true or false substantively, if, again, we think schemes to be too semantically impoverished to be true or false.) Now, I'm not an expert in the philosophy of semantics, so I don't know what relevant technical obstacles there are to proclaiming that it is possible to refer to actual *possibilia* (in the event that there are such things) just as "intentionally" as it is possible to refer to fully actual objects in the empirically physical world. On the other hand, if fictional objects are mental/social objects and these have an expressly empirical/physical appearance, then it is easier to account for a reference to mathematical objects as such. Lastly, if mathematical objects are separated out of empirical space but not space altogether (not abstract space, that is), then we have the identification problem to consider.

The SEP article on Zermelo's axiomatization of set theory includes in its opening paragraphs a reference to "these principles [distilled from the actual operation with sets]," which suggests that Zermelo would have been ostensively "pointing at" our *a priori* operational awareness of element-set relations. However, we know that the gap between set-builder and ∈-notation yields different theorems depending on how the set-builder notation is used to 'reconstruct' the natural numbers. This deep "enigma," concerning what are almost reducible to notational variants, lends deep support to formalism/if-then-ism, in turn, so though by means of the argument of the endnote we gave ourselves sufficient reason to doubt if-then-ism, now the seeming primary alternative has also been to some extent undermined. Perhaps the best thing to do would be to eschew set-builder notation altogether?

At any rate, there is room for stipulativism and ostensivism to blur together, as well as room for them to be set at odds with each other. (Of course, nothing said here rules out accepting that there are both legitimate stipulativist and ostensivist axioms even if they do not seem to blur together regardless.) My question is: **as a "Rawlsian" replacement concept for the formalist/realist divide, how serviceable is the stipulativist/ostensivist divide?** I can anticipate the objection that the blurriness of the "new" concept is not cognate with the hard-edged base concept, in the sense that being an absolutely transfinite *ante rem* reality can be clearly understood to be something other than being a historically local semiotic convention or mathematically "thin" game of symbols/syntax; we'd have to emphasize the subset of ostensivists who would hold that the "this" of an axiomatic ostensive definition sentence was an *ante rem* reality. But then we haven't really "replaced" the "old" concept with the "new" one. On the other hand, if we say that mathematics is a game, then we can still ask about a sort of generalized asemic game, and this will have logical features, so game-theoretic formalism will start to bleed into a more referential logicism, and eventually we will even be able to blend intuitionism into ZFC and this into other philosophies of mathematics, so that the blurriness of the "new" alternative might not conclusively testify to the discursive weakness of this alternative, since after all the traditional dividing lines are blurry, too.

<sup>♃</sup><sub>This would be my objection to "raw" if-then-ism: suppose, for example, that truth is correspondence to facts. Then treating a sentence "as if" it is true is treating it as corresponding to a fact. But if the sentence does not correspond to a fact, it will be false. So either there are internally stipulative facts (or: it is possible for some kind of state of affairs to obtain by virtue of the stipulation that it obtains), or stipulative definition uniformly produces *false* sentences, or even worse, meaningless ones. Of these three options, the first admits of a plausible reformulation: if stipulative definitions are reducible to announcements of how one is going to use certain symbols in a certain context, then there will be facts about the things one has actually announced in that context.</sub>

<sub>At any rate, however, even from a deflationary vantage, we would advert to the disquotation scheme to "explain" truth, so that if we "treat" a sentence "as if" it is true, then we treat the meaning of that sentence as if it were a fact or obtaining state of affairs, e.g. if we treat, "Snow is blue," as true then we think/imagine snow being blue. Or if we treat, "There exist 19, and only 19, uncountable strongly inaccessible cardinals," as true, then we think/imagine exactly 19 such cardinals being existent. Or if we treat, "Structure *A* is isomorphic to structure *B*," as true, then we think/imagine *A* being isomorphic to *B*. And so on and on. Saying that we treat things "as if" they were true does not mean we disconnect the possible meaning of what we say, from what is actually supposed to be true. Pretense and fiction only "work" given a more factive background; it would be surprising for something as elementary as mathematics to be pretentious or fictional more than not (not to deny that there can be moments of pretense/fiction, or similar "phenomena," e.g. some of the really weird choices in word usage (... e.g., the terms *mouse* and *premouse*; these have clear enough definitions, and there is even an infinitely subtle way in which the meaning resembles the idea of a small scurrying creature, but even so...)). Or even worse, fictional sentences are actually just true after all (not so much pretenses, but their untruth is the falsehood of mendacity), because they refer to actually possible objects, or to actual imaginal objects, or actual social objects, or whatever.</sub>

Comment: If math contains many ostensive definitions it will cease to be watertight, but as your Russell quote shows the language of math ultimately sourced from ostensive primitive concepts. Intuitionism rejecting LEM can be seen as more towards ostensivism since LEM is clearly stipulative when containing universal closure sentences with infinite domain. And Beth's theorem with implicit definition in an admissible extended theory is more towards stipulativism while may violate the conservative and eliminable criteria demanded by ostensive ideal from straightforward explicit definitional expansion...